# Software Requirements Analysis

Tags: language-agnostic, requirements, requirements-management

There are many tools out there for writing and managing requirements, but are there any good ones for reviewing them?

I'm not talking about ***managing*** reviews, but automation tools that look for common requirement blunders (such as using negative requirements, or ones that are worded in a way that makes testing difficult).
More of a screening tool that someone writing requirements can use to screen their document before distributing to a group of reviewers so that the review process need not be slowed down by everyone commenting on the same easily recognizable issues.

I'm curious if anyone's used anything like this in the past.

Comment: Could be tagged tool and requirements-management

Comment: I think title is a little bit broad for the question. (in my opinion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm working on a console application that takes a xml configuration file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReqCheck>
  <Categories name="Reconsider wording">
    <Keyword>may</Keyword>
    <Keyword>should</Keyword>
  </Categories>
  <Categories name="Potential logic problem" format="{0}: consider both then and else conditions.">
    <Keyword>not</Keyword>
  </Categories>
</ReqCheck>
```

The application takes a MS-Word document and adds 'balloon-style' comments to the document.

Comment: This sounds promising, will you be distributing this as shareware once it's working?

Comment: I would like to take a look at this as well. Very interesting concept.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Ravenflow products](http://www.ravenflow.com/). I did not try them myself yet, but their features seem to be very close to what you are looking for...

**NB:** Ravenflow products are likely to be prohibitively expensive for small- and even medium-size teams/companies...

Comment: Cite from their website: An Enterprise bundle of unlimited, worldwide
access to all three RAVEN products is $1,000,000.00 per year.